# Is it possible to start Google Drive paused?

Tags: google-drive

Is there a way to run Google Drive on Windows startup but keep the synchronization paused until I enable it manually?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What have you attempted so far?

Comment: @CharlieRB Since it wasn't clear enough for you, I added the word "synchronization" to the post. The GUI only offers an option to enable or disable it altogether on logon, and I'm wondering if there's a shortcut parameter or something else I can use to launch it paused.